# What is the decision function used in sklearn's SVC SVM

Tags: svm, scikit-learn

When I am using sklearn.svm.SVC I have set the decision function to 'ovr', but am struggling to find the exact decision function equation at the moment. Can anyone help me out? 
Thanks in advance.